# Contar elementos numa coluna no excel em especifico pelo google colab/ python

Tags: python

Estou tentando contar elementos repetidos de uma coluna no excel pelo google colab/ python, como posso estar fazendo esta execução?

Comment: sem o minimo de codigo fica dificil interpretar onde esta com dificuldades. 2 soluções é pela apis **pandas** e tbm **xlrd**

Comment: Eu sou iniciante, queria saber um modo de ler apenas uma coluna do arquivo no excel e contar elementos

Answer (score 0):

Se está usando o Colab, o melhor é carregar a planilha como um dataframe e usar os métodos do Pandas para tal. Como deseja a contagem dos elementos que se repetem em uma determinada coluna pode usar o método value_counts (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html). Na verdade, esse método vai retornar a frequência de todos os valores únicos da coluna, não apenas os que se repetem.

Estarei supondo que sua dúvida seja somente com a contagem dos elementos de determinada coluna. A forma utilizada abaixo para carregar a planilha pelo Colab será diferente, a depender se estiver no seu drive ou no seu disco local. A biblioteca utilizada é a pd.read_excel (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

```
df = pd.read_excel("seu arquivo.xlsx")

# Seleciona a coluna e aplica o value_counts()
df["nome da coluna"].value_counts()
```

Há inúmeras outras formas, mas essa deve atender ao que deseja, de modo simples. Se precisar acessar qualquer valor desses que retornaram, aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso: [Retornar soma de casos de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/576056/retornar-soma-de-casos-de-uma-tabela/576065#576065)