# Retornar soma de casos de uma tabela

Tags: python, pandas, value

Utilizando a base de dados dos passageiros do Titanic, preciso contar o número de sobreviventes e "printar" a seguinte mensagem: "O número de sobreviventes é igual a: 342 pessoas"

Até o momento, estou utilizando o código a seguir:

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('../dados/titanic.csv')

df['sobreviveu'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
nao    549
sim    342
Name: sobreviveu, dtype: int64
```

Como consigo fazer isso, ou seja, selecionar um valor específico?

Comment: `print("O número de sobreviventes é igual a:", df[df['sobreviveu'] == 'sim'].shape[0], "pessoas")` acho que seria simples em uma unica linha

Answer (score -1):

Note que a expressão `df['sobreviveu'].value_counts()`retorna uma Série.

Para facilitar vou atribuir ela a uma variável v:

`v = df['sobreviveu'].value_counts()`.

Pode verificar com `type(v)`. E então você pode acessar os índices e valores dela dessa forma:

```
v.index
v.values
```

Então, para acessar o valor de determinado índice, use v[0], v[1], etc.

No seu caso, teremos:

`print(f"O número de sobreviventes é igual a {v[1]} pessoas")`. Altere o índice conforme sua necessidade.